# double integral to simple integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

this question is probably simple but i just can't find out how to change this double integral to simple integral. Can you please help me? :)

Thanks very much for your help!

f is a continuous/C1 function (verifying all the hypothesis to be integrable)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The relationship in the highlighted box of the OP is not generally true.  For example, if $f$ is an odd function then $\int_0^T\int_0^T f(t-u)\,dt\,du=0$ while $2\int_0^T(T-x)f(x)\,dx$ need not be $0$ when $f$ is odd (Take $f(x)=x$, for example).

However, we can assert that the relationship holds for all even functions.  To show this we will write $f(x)=f^e(x)+f^o(x)$ where $f^e$ and $f^o$ are the even and odd components of $f$, respectively and given by

$$f^e(x)=\frac12 (f(x)+f(-x))\\\\f^o(x)=\frac12 (f(x)-f(-x))$$

Next, enforcing the substitution $x=t-u$ in the inner integral yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^T\int_0^T f(t-u)\,dt\,du&\overbrace{=}^{x=t-u}\int_0^T\int_{-u}^{T-u}f(x)\,dx\,du\\\\
&=\int_0^T \int_0^{T-x}f(x)\,du\,dx+\int_{-T}^0\int_{-x}^T f(x)\,du\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^T f(x) \int_0^{T-x}(1)\,du\,dx+\int_{-T}^0 f(x)\int_{-x}^T(1)\,du\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^T (T-x)f(x)\,dx+\int_{-T}^0(T+x)f(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^T (T-x)(f(x)+f(-x))\,dx\\\\
&=2\int_0^T(T-x)f^e(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$

Hence, we find that

> $$\int_0^T\int_0^T f(t-u)\,dt\,du=2\int_0^T(T-x)f^e(x)\,dx\tag 1$$

Note that we could have written

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^T\int_0^T f(t-u)\,dt\,du&=\int_0^T\int_0^T f^e(t-u)\,dt\,du+\overbrace{\int_0^T\int_0^T f^o(t-u)\,dt\,du}^{=0}\\\\
&=\int_0^T\int_0^T f^e(t-u)\,dt\,du\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields

> $$\int_0^T\int_0^T f^e(t-u)\,dt\,du=2\int_0^T(T-x)f^e(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I don't understand how the boundaries of the integral changed from lign 1 to 2. Also there is 2 multiplicative factor missing if I am not mistaken?

Comment: Another thing : if we take f =1 for instance, on the left part we have T^2 whereas on your right part we have T^2 /2 isn't it?

Comment: @phacoo You're welcome.  It was my pleasure.  Your comments highlighted a flaw in the development, which I have corrected.  As it turns out, the relationship in the highlighted area in the OP is not generally true.  However, it is true for even functions as the edited development reveals.  -Mark

Comment: thanks very much for your answer very clear! a last question: how to do you get from the first to the second line (when you split the integrals)?

Comment: thanks very much for the highlights, all clear now!

Comment: It was my pleasure.  And since you're new to MSE, I wanted to let you know that you can up vote once you've accrued enough reputation points.